# Konva converting shapes toDataUrl() results in blank image

Tags: canvas, konvajs

I have Konva Stage with few layers, when I try convert to image all stage - result is OK, when I try convert layer - result is OK. But when I try convert shapes, like Text, Image, Rekt toDataUrl(), it gives me blank transparent image with shape sizes.
Here's [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8bh2a6qo/7/)

```
<div id="container"></div>
<div id="image">
  <img id="imageData" src="https://github.com/rafaesc/vue-konva/raw/master/vue-konva.png" width="100">
</div>

const stage = new Konva.Stage({
   container: 'container',
   width:400,
   height: 200
});

const layer = new Konva.Layer();
stage.add(layer);

const text = new Konva.Text({
   x: 100,
   y: 100,
   width: 200,
   height: 40,
   fill: "gray",
   stroke: "gray",
   align: 'center',
   verticalAlign: 'middle',
   text: 'Text',
   fontSize: 24
});

layer.add(text).draw();
var textToImg = text.toDataURL();
document.getElementById('imageData').src=textToImg;
```

Any possible reasons or solutions? Thanks

Comment: Can you make a small demo?

Comment: @lavrton yes, sure, JSfiddle added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default behaviour will be fixed in the next `Konva` release to adjust position automatically. For now, you need to set `x` and `y` and `toDataURL` config:

```
var textToImg = text.toDataURL({
  x: text.x(),
  y: text.y(),
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/yh52esmL/